# Error while calling stored procedure using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to call an Oracle stored procedure using JPA EntityManager. The stored procedure returns a list of the orders joining multiple tables for a date range. The stored procedure works good when I test it at the database end. Below is my code to make the call

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("Get_submitted_orders")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .setParameter(2, storeCode)
                .setParameter(3, fromDate, TemporalType.DATE)
                .setParameter(4, toDate, TemporalType.DATE);

        List<Object[]> orders = query.getResultList();
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
```

Comment: can you add more stacktrace?

Comment: And it will be perfect, if you'll add DDL for your procedure "Get_submitted_orders"

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has 2 problems. 
First of all, the REF_CURSOR class should be void.class

```
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
```

The seccond one, before calling getResultList() yoy should execute your query

```
query.execute();
List<Object[]> orders = query.getResultList();
```

Hope this helps!